# How to share the same environment file with Helm and Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

The `docker-compose` will automatically read the `.env` file if it resides in a same with the `docker-compose.yml` directory. With this in mind, I go ahead and in `.env` file define the `app-container` environment variable to store the container URL, like so:

```
app-container=12345.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/container-image:v003
```

In a `docker-compose.yml` file I then substitute the container URL with the environment variable `app-container`.

```
    version: '3'

    services:
      app1:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: my.dockerfile
          image: ${app-container}
```

It would be great if I could pass the same `app-container` environment variable to substitute the container's URL defined in Helm's `values.yaml` file. So, instead of storing the container's URL explicitly

```
app:
  image: 12345.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/container-image:v003
```

the Helm's `values.yaml` file could use the same `app-container` environment variable that was already defined in `.env` file and used by `docker-compose`. The Helm's `values.yaml` file could be then simply defined as:

```
app:
  image: ${app-container}
```

I wonder if sharing the same `env` file between `docker-compose` and Helm is possible?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, its little hacky way:

- First set the environment variable from `.env` file.

```
$ cat .env
appcontainer=12345.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/container-image:v003
$ while read LINE; do export "$LINE"; done < .env
```

***NOTE:*** You need to remove `-` from `app-container` name. Otherwise you will get this error while setting environment variable `bash: export: app-container=12345.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/container-image:v003': not a valid identifier`

- Now explicitly set that env in values.yaml using `--set` option.

```
helm install --set app.image=$appcontainer ./mychart
```

But ideally it would be good to have separate env for your `docker-compose` and `helm chart`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can do ``` set -a;  . .env; set +a``` to avoid having to do that loop then pass the variables into your helm command. And if you are running the helm command in the same shell that you are sourcing the env file in you dont actually need to export them. Exporting is to allow subshells to inherit variables. But over all @mchawre approach is what I do. It is very useful for CI if you want your config to come from env variables (like bitbucket pipelines variables)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, you would have to write a script to convert one format into the other.